# How can i be notified on (succesfull and failed) logins in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

i want to be notified when someone tries to login to my sql server (2008); whether it succeeded or not.
I found the 'alert' section under the 'sql server agent', but didn't find anything like it there.

Michel

Comment: Do you want to be notified immediately or just be able to browse through the login events?

Comment: immediately, browsig i will probably forget :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is logging it to the windows eventlog and ERRORLOG good enough?  if so.
Using SSMS:

1. Right-click the database server in
   object explorer and go to properties
2. Click on the security page
3. Select *Both failed and successful
   logins* on the login auditing option

Comment: that was nice, the eventlog gives me the opportunity to send email when some events occur, so this does the trick

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that feature is available built in but you can set up some scripts to do it.  Try [here](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/alerts-for-when-logins-failures-strike) for an example.